# EF Not including foreignkey uses the last object of the foreign type

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

EF 6, VS 2013, Local DB.

I have a very basic Entity Framework test project. It has `Users` and `Blogs`.

Every user can have many blogs, and a blog has a foreign key relating to the user.

I create a `User`, and a blog, but I don't connect them. EF made the connection without me telling it to.

If I don't create the `User` object, it errors as I wanted it to. I.e. don't save an object missing a required field.

```
public class FieldSizes
{
    public const int Names = 32;
    public const int Long = 80;
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using(Dbf db = new Dbf())
        {
            var user = db.Users.Create();
            user.PasswordHash = "tests";
            user.UserName = "sssss";
            db.Users.Add(user);

            var blog = db.Blogs.Create();
            blog.Title = "gssss";
            blog.ContentId = 42;
            db.Blogs.Add(blog);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}

public class Dbf : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Blog> Blogs { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(FieldSizes.Names)]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    public string PasswordHash { get; set; }

    public void SetPassword(string password)
    {
        this.PasswordHash = "[Encryption Key]";
    }

    public virtual List<Blog> Blogs { get; set; }
}

public class Blog
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("User")]
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    public virtual User User { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(FieldSizes.Long)]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public int ContentId { get; set; }
}
```

Is this by design in EF? Is there a mistake in my code? I don't understand why EF is doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's by design, but it's something that will be a problem if we're not aware about it.

When you created a new `User`, EF will assign a temporary key as primary key. The newly created `User` will have temporary Id = 0 since it's a default value of integer. The key is a temporary key and if it's an identity key, it will be updated after it's saved.

More: [EntityKey.IsTemporary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entitykey.istemporary%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

And when you created a new `Blog`, the default value of `UserId` is also 0. And it will cause `Blog` and `User` have relationship in the database.

You can also assign temporary key manually to make a relationship.

```
user.Id = 1234;
blog.UserId = 1234;
```

This is a [great article](http://www.ladislavmrnka.com/2011/05/foreign-key-vs-independent-associations-in-ef-4/) explaining about this case. Here is part of the excerpt.

> When creating a new relation we just need a dependent entity and a
>   primary key of a parent entity. The tricky part here is that primary
>   key must be unique for all attached entities of a given type. Even if
>   we use auto generated keys in the database we must still assign
>   temporary unique key to newly created entities which are added to
>   relations.

Comment: Seems a bit wrong, I don't think it worked like that in EF5. What happens if you add multiple users and multiple blogs?

Comment: If you have new multiple users (Id = 0) and at least one new blog where UserId = 0, `db.Users.Add(new User()); db.Users.Add(new User()); db.Blogs.Add(new Blog()); db.SaveChanges();`, this will throw exception.. `Unable to determine the principal end of the 'Blog_User' relationship. Multiple added entities may have the same primary key.`

Comment: I don't know about EF5, but the temporary key has been there since .net 3.5, should be the same, but I haven't tested yet

Comment: This makes sense.  I don't like it, but it makes sense.  It seems like there should be a safe value, like int.MinimumValue, and if it equals that then go purely off the virtual relationships that were used.

Comment: @DanVioletSagmiller, it can help creating relationship for new principal and new dependent actually, but developer needs to be aware of it